# Nginx log file decode character

Tags: nginx

I would like to encode the http characters into the log file

instead of logging this

```
"20/Aug/2014:17:19:06 -0400","127.0.0.1","uid","suid","35604c31-c61b-484a-95aa-ca17f85fa8ae","-","prod\x22uct","category","actuoi","label","2","{\x22say\x22:\x22hello\x22}"
```

i would like to log this

```
"20/Aug/2014:17:19:06 -0400","127.0.0.1","uid","suid","35604c31-c61b-484a-95aa-ca17f85fa8ae","-","prod\x22uct","category","actuoi","label","2","{"say":"hello"}"
```

The `\x22` will be decoded it `"`

Any idea please.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Your quotes are now ambiguous.

Comment: Because, i want to parse this file later on, and i want to keep it the original version.

Comment: You don't want this. Really. It's better to modify your parser or preprocess log before give it to parser.

Comment: @FadhelGhorbel How would you parse this with ambiguous quotes?

Comment: I could remove the double quote surrounds each field. Those quotes are not necessary. I want to keep to json object structure as i mentionned i want to keep this format {"say":"hello"} and not {\x22say\x22:\x22hello\x22}

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for this. Have you found anything ?